# Sort items of globals() by created time

Tags: python

Working in IPython, I input 3 assignments:

```
In [1]: foo = 1

In [2]: bar = 2

In [3]: zoo = 3
```

I intend to fetch a dict of them.

```
In [4]: globals()
Out[4]: 
{...
 'bar': 2,
 'exit': <IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall at 0x10e61b048>,
 'foo': 1,
 'get_ipython': <bound method InteractiveShell.get_ipython of <IPython.terminal.interactiveshell.TerminalInteractiveShell object at 0x10e617208>>,
 'quit': <IPython.core.autocall.ExitAutocall at 0x10e61b048>,
 'zoo': 3}
```

`globals` prints a dict in an alphabetical order, so I cannot select them all with one opearation.

How to get an dict from globals() in assignnent_created order?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, because it is rather unclear why you would want to do what you are asking for.

Comment: I don't think that python keeps track of when variables are assigned. So it would be difficult to do this. What problem are you trying to solve by doing this? It doesn't seem like something that anyone would ever want to do.

Comment: in time order, the 3 assignments will be at bottom or at the top.So it's esay to copy them all at a single operation.

Comment: Do you want the time they were first assigned or the most recent assignment?

Comment: ya, the most recent assignment.

Comment: This looks like an x-y problem.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Over hours, global() will prints mountains of data,amongst them,usually just want the recent ones.

Comment: I  want to review all the assignments in a summarize view in time order.

Comment: I get the idea.Python does not track.

Comment: you may want to look at using the IPython magic command `%history -l 100`

Comment: It seems python does track, there should be a solution to global() @James

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158652/discussion-between-james-and-defu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, globals doesn't track the order of creation.
Secondly, you can try removing unwanted items and then sorting the dictionary like so:

```
remove_keys = ['exit', 'get_ipython']
g = sorted(
        dict(
            (k,v) for k,v in globals() 
            if k not in remove_keys
        )
    )
```

Comment: It's a solution to the dict, not to the global.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.